# How can I apply a condition to a list comprehension?

Tags: python

What I need to be able to do is grab all the 'id' and 'img_uris' for only the products with an 'origin' of 'US'.

Here is a rough sample of the data I am working with.

```
[
  {
    "product_type": "widget",
    "id": "1744556-ghh56h-4633",
    "manufacture_id": "AAB4567",
    "language": "en",
    "store_ids": [
      416835,
      456145
    ],
    "name": "Best Widget",
    "origin": "US",
    "manufactured": "2018-08-26",
    "uri": "https://bobswidgets.com/best_widget",
    "image_uris": {
      "small": "https://bobswidgets.com/small/best_widget_sm.jpg",
      "normal": "https://bobswidgets.com/medium/best_widget_md.jpg",
      "large": "https://bobswidgets.com/large/best_widget_lg.jpg"
    },
    "manufacture_cost": "12.50"
  },
  {
    "product_type": "widget",
    "id": "0956786-dje596-3904",
    "manufacture_id": "BCD13D",
    "language": "en",
    "store_ids": [
      "014329",
      "40123"
    ],
    "name": "Best Widget2",
    "origin": "US",
    "manufactured": "2018-10-03",
    "uri": "https://bobswidgets.com/best_widget_2",
    "image_uris": {
      "small": "https://bobswidgets.com/small/best_widget2_sm.jpg",
      "normal": "https://bobswidgets.com/medium/best_widget2_md.jpg",
      "large": "https://bobswidgets.com/large/best_widget2_lg.jpg"
    },
    "manufacture_cost": "13.33"
  }
]
```

I was using this code to loop through the json and extract just the 'id' and 'normal' URL from 'img_uris'.

```
import ujson as json
import pandas as pd

with open('product.json', 'r') as f:
    json_text = f.read()

prod_dict = json.loads(json_text)
prod_image = [{d['id']: d.get('image_uris', {}).get('normal', 'N/A')} for d in prod_dict]
```

This works great then I realized that there seemed to be more products than there should be. Turns out that not all of the products have an 'origin' of 'US'. I've been trying to figure out how to add a condition to the list comprehension to grab only those that have 'US' as the 'origin' with no luck. Most examples I have found are pretty simplistic and are not dealing with dictionaries.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work.

```
prod_image = [{d['id']: d.get('image_uris', {}).get('normal', 'N/A')} for d in card_dict if d['origin'] = 'US']
```

Comment: In an if statement, for a comparisson operator you need `==`, not `=`

Comment: So you made all that effort to write the question, and managed to solve it and write that answer in 30 seconds?

Comment: @yatu My same thoughts. I'm marking this question for closing, it was just a typo.

Comment: Yeah. That is typically how it works with me. I'll bang my head on things forever and then when I post a question I figure it out shortly after. In this case I had figured it out while writing the question and decided to post it for anyone else who might have this struggle. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final block should work however you have an assignment `=` rather than a boolean `==`.

```
prod_image = [{d['id']: d.get('image_uris', {}).get('normal', 'N/A')} for d in card_dict if d['origin'] == 'US']
```

Comment: I definitely needed more coffee this morning. I realized what I did wrong as I was typing the question out. I think the process of reproducing simplified code here and asking the question in a clear and concise manner clears away some cobwebs when I get stuck.